# HTML - Why does textarea has no maxlength attribute?

Tags: html, specifications

What is the reason why `textarea` before HTML5 has no `maxlength` attribute? There must be reason for this, did they (author of HTML) miss it or did they do it on purpose? What is the purpose? I'm not looking for the solution on how to implement `maxlength` in `textarea`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textarea element **does** have a maxlength attribute as of HTML5. Hoorah! If you want to make guesses at why it wasn't implemented in HTML4, a good guess would be that a textarea was intended to be used for a potentially unknown amount of text and setting a maximum length didn't seem plausible at the time, but they've since been proven wrong. But that's all you can really get is guesses.

Comment: text field also used for unknown amount of characters though they still put up maxlength attribute... I guess you're right, we can only get guesses here. I visited to w3.org but no luck looking for answer. Let's just wait for others to shed some light.

Comment: An input field can only be one line of text though. It's a much smaller frame of what kinds of input can fit into one line.